# JavaScript Array Function - Selecting one engineer a day

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I'm solving 'Support Wheel of Fate' problem which needs to be implemented in JS using 3 conditions.

1. 2 Engineers should be selected daily from a pool of 10 engineers.
2. Selected engineers cannot be selected on next day.
3. When an engineer serves two times, his count will be reset to 0.

I'm having a problem with the 2nd condition. Here's my code for solving this problem

```
const filterEligibleEngineers = (allEngineers, shiftToday) => {
  const newShiftYesterday = shiftToday;


  let meetsCriteria;
  // if some engineers worked less than one shift, select from that pool
  if (allEngineers.some(eng => eng.shifts_worked < 1)) {
    meetsCriteria = (engineer) => {
      const rules = !newShiftYesterday.includes(engineer.name) &&
            engineer.shifts_worked < 1;
      return rules;
    }
  }

  // one engineer cannot work on consecutive days
  else if (allEngineers.some(eng => eng.shiftToday && eng.shifts_worked === 1)) {


    meetsCriteria = (engineer) => {
      const rules = !newShiftYesterday.filter(engineer.name) && engineer.shifts_worked === 1;
      return rules;
    }
    console.log('Consecutive days logged');
    // return allEngineers.map((engineer) =>{
    // //   return engineer;
    // });
  }


  // all engineers reached the 2 shift limit, reset the shifts_worked count
  else if (allEngineers.every(eng => eng.shifts_worked === 2)) {
    return allEngineers.map(engineer => {
      engineer.shifts_worked = 0;
      return engineer;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you're putting in to your function (format of a `shift` & `engineer`) and what you're expecting it to return v.s. what it does right now. (throws an error? gives the wrong result?)

Comment: @user3297291 I get the same user again.